# A condition that implies $f_* \mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{O}_S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, picard-scheme

I am reading the lecture note of Dori Bejleri about Picard schemes:
[https://people.math.harvard.edu/~bejleri/teaching/math259xfa19/math259x_lecture12.pdf](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ebejleri/teaching/math259xfa19/math259x_lecture12.pdf)

In Example 12.8, I don't understand why the smooth and irreducible generic fiber implies that $f:X\rightarrow S$ is a universal algebraic fiber space, i.e. $f_* \mathcal{O}_X \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathcal{O}_S$ holds universally.

I have tried to find some conditions to be a universal algebraic fiber space, but I only find a condition in the notes of Picard schemes of Kleiman (Exercise 3.11, when $f:X \rightarrow S$ is proper and flat and its geometric fibers are reduced and connected):
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504020

Can anyone help me to explain the example of Bejleri? Are there any other conditions implying this universal isomorphism?

Comment: If you mean Example 1 in the linked PDF, I definitely should have added an assumption that all the fibers are reduced. The example is local on the base so you can for example shrink $\mathbb{A}^1$ to some open neighborhood of $0$ which avoids non-reduced fibers or you can pick $f$ appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much.